# Oracle APEX: Issue capturing Close Region

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex21.2

I have a region on the page - Inline Dialog and I need to capture when region is being closed using `Close Region` action.

I created a DA on `Dialog Close`

Event: Dialog Closed
Selection Type: Region
Region:  MyRegionBeingClosed

But that does not work. Behind the scenes `NATIVE_CLOSE_REGION` is being fired. How can I capture it with a DA?

Answer (score 1):

- Give the inline dialog a static id of "inline-dialog"
- Create a DA with the following settings:
  [image]